# Maximum Likelihood Estimator for area of circle

Tags: normal-distribution, maximum-likelihood, inference

I have been working on the following question:

> The radius of a circle, $R$, is measured with an error of measurement which is is normally distributed with mean $0$ and variance $\sigma^2$, given $n$ independent measurements of $R$ find the maximum likelihood estimator for the area of the circle

This is what I did:

> Let $X_i$ be the $i$-th measurement of the radius. We have that $X_i=R+e_i$, where $e_i$ is the error for this measurement. From that it follows that $X$ is normally distributed with mean $R$ and variance $\sigma^2$.
>
> We know that the MLE for the mean of a nomally distributed random variable is $\bar{X}$, therefore $\hat{R}=\bar{X}$ and it follows from the invariance principle that $\hat{A}=\pi \hat{R}^2=\pi\bar{X}^2$.

Now, I was told that approach is wrong and that the right thing to do is to consider $n$ measurements of the radius $R_i=\mu+e_i$ and from this we would have $n$ measurements of the area $A_i=\pi R_i^2$.

From that it would follow that $E[A_i]=\pi(\mu^2+\sigma^2)$ and that we need to estimate the parameters for the distribution of $A$ which would be $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$.

I don't understand why my approach is wrong and the other one is right, it looks the opposite to me. I later asked if $\mu$ is the real radius of the circle and was told no, with no explanation. It looks to me as this second approach is estimating the mean of the area, are they different? If yes, what is the difference?

Could anyone explain a bit more why is that?
Any tips, ideas, or explanations are most welcome.